# How to create a parameter and use inside a custom sql query in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a list of countries.
I need to create a parameter that can be used inside a custom sql.

For Eg:
List of countries

Argentina,Brazil,Colombia,Ecuador...

The requirement is
User should be able to select multiple countries

Based on that selection, need to run a custom sql that uses SQL IN query or multiple OR.

If user select Argentina and Brazil

Custom sql will be like

select * from players where countries in ('Argentina','Brazil)'

I tried with Set and Filters. But how can I create a parameter based on the selection of filters/Sets?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are single select only. So in your scenario it is not possible. You could create multiple parameters but that would mean the user would need to pick a country for each otherwise your query would not work. Here are instructions for creating and using parameters in custom sql. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.htm#use-parameters-in-a-custom-sql-query

Comment: Yes. Single select is working fine. But we can't limit or force the user to select N or M number of countries.